# SQL correct definition of floating points

Tags: mysql, sql

I am measuring some values over a geo-location
I need to create a table that consists of:

```
date 
longitude
latitude
value
```

The date column is the date of the measure, 
The value is just an int value of the measure, 
the longitude and latitude are a coordinates - they are floating points columns with 3 digits before the point and 5 after (i.e. ***.*****)

I'm wondering how to define my table, I try to use:

```
CREATE TABLE `obs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `lon` decimal(5,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` decimal(5,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is a link to [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/036dae)

But When I'm trying to run

```
INSERT INTO `obs` VALUES (null,'2014/06/07','34.000','31.342',1)
```

I am getting the following error:

> Out of range value for column 'lon' at row 1:

Can anyone explain me what's wrong?

Comment: BTW  `decimal` is a *fixed-point* and not a *floating-point*.

Answer (score 3):

`decimal(5,5)` means

```
5 decimal places in TOTAL
5 decimal places after the point
```

That would make all numbers invalid having a decimal place **before** the point.

You probably want

```
decimal(10,5)
```